# Price string to float

Tags: php

I like to convert string with a price to a float value. The price comes from different languages and countries and can look like this:

```
 1,00 €
 € 1.00
 1'000,00 EUR
 1 000.00$
 1,000.00$
 1.000,00 EURO
```

or whatever you can think of...

Not sure I got the full range of possibilities with my examples. I am also not sure if it is possible to make in international convert blindly, maybe I have to use a language code? So for the start Euro and Dollar would be enough.

`floatval()` is kind of stupid so I need something more here. I think I should first remove all chars beside numbers, `,` and `.`. Then fix the `,` / `.` and use floatval finally.

Has someone done this before and can help me a little?

I would prefer a solution without regexp ;)

**Update**: Current solution with tests https://onlinephp.io/c/9e95e

Comment: why without regex? That limits you greatly...

Comment: So the input is variable, even when dots and zeroes might mean thousands separator or decimal point.. and you think that there's a magic hammer for this, for all possible inputs you might receive from your users?

Comment: @Nick I said "prefer" because I think regexp are hard to read and difficult to maintain. But I would still use them if I need to.

Comment: @N.B. That is the fact we are facing see [here](http://www.google.de/products/catalog?q=all+in+one+pc&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=878&ie=UTF-8&cid=8971864444259043600&sa=X&ei=eWYqT4DWBObY4QTuyMiADg&ved=0CKEBEPMCMAM) and [here](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/877094/Joy-IT-Industrie-PC-INDUS-T15-Touch-One-381-cm-15-Intel-Atom-N525-2x18-GHz-2048-MB-250-GB-Intel-GMA-FreeDOS/0413089&ref=list). And so I think others had faced this problem before. A magic hammer would be nice!

Comment: I get the issue you're having, but the problem is that you don't have the input that's constant. Sometimes you have `1,000.00` which represents a thousand. You an also have `1000.00` which is again 1 thousand. You can also have `100,00` which is a hundred (in my country we don't use the dot for decimal separator). So the question is how to interpret prices you encounter, it can vary. You need to set some ground rules, such as what's decimal separator and what's thousands separator. After that it's trivial to determine the price - skip everything that's not `.` or `,` or numeric character.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, I tried it myself. What do you think of this?

```
function priceToFloat($s){
    // is negative number
    $neg = strpos((string)$s, '-') !== false;
    
    // convert "," to "."
    $s = str_replace(',', '.', $s);

    // remove everything except numbers and dot "."
    $s = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "", $s);

    // remove all seperators from first part and keep the end
    $s = str_replace('.', '',substr($s, 0, -3)) . substr($s, -3);

    // Set negative number
    if( $neg ) {
        $s = '-' . $s;
    }

    // return float
    return (float) $s;
}
```

Here some tests: https://onlinephp.io/c/9e95e

Sorry. I couldn't include the other functions because codepad did not like them. But I compared them and there was trouble with strings like "22 000,76" or "22.000"

Update: As [Limitless isa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363737/956397) pointed out you might have a look at the build in function [money-format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: Seems like it should do the trick. Just out of curiosity, the filter_var approach didn't work for you?

Comment: @Oldskool the filter_var solutions is _very_ nice! But it does not work for prices without cents.

Comment: You need to add the flag `filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);`

Comment: @JacobThomason I run my tests with this function but it fails in many cases even with a simple "1,00": http://codepad.org/Uax6Hnar

Comment: Don't forget about negative numbers.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work with currencies of 3 decimals (such as Tunisian Dinar) ...

Comment: @SimonTrichereau True, this works for 2 decimals only. This would work for you I guess: http://codepad.org/AxQjGimG
It does not work for me as 22,000 is 22000 and not 22 in most cases here.

Answer (score 2):

Removing all the non-numeric characters should give you the price in cents. You can then divide that by 100 to get the 'human readable' price. You could do this with something like the [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT. For example:

```
$cents = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$price = floatval($cents / 100);
```

Above is untested, but something like that is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: This is not true at all, it only works if the price is given with 2 decimals, but some currencies have no decimals (for example the japanese Yen JPY), and some have 3 decimals (for example the Tunisian Dinar TND)

Answer (score 2):

This function will fix your problem:

```
function priceToSQL($price)
{
    $price = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]*/i', '', $price);
    $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);

    if(substr($price, -3, 1) == '.')
    {
        $price = explode('.', $price);
        $last = array_pop($price);
        $price = join($price, '').'.'.$last;
    }
    else
    {
        $price = str_replace('.', '', $price);
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works very nice for most cases. I still found some examples the function has problems with like "22 000,76" and "22.000". I tried to build my [own version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9111507/956397).

Comment: I fixed it with the cases you provided and it work perfectly now.

Comment: +1 Works fine now. Well done! This night a good an idea, I can do the same now in three lines. Check it out.

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't work with currencies of 3 digits ... (example Tunisian Diram) ...

Answer (score 1):

To remove all but numbers, commas and full stops:

```
<?php

$prices = array( "1,00 €",
 "€ 1.00",
 "1'000,00 EUR",
 "1 000.99$",
 "1,000.01$",
 "1.000,10 EURO");

$new_prices = array();
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    $new_prices[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9,\.]/", "", $price);
}

print_r($new_prices);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1,00 [1] => 1.00 [2] => 1000,00 [3] => 1000.99 [4] => 1,000.01 [5] => 1.000,10 )
```

Now lets utilize the parseFloat function from [Michiel - php.net](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php#84793) (I won't paste it here since it's a pretty big function):

```
<?php

$prices = array( "1,00 €",
 "€ 1.00",
 "1'000,00 EUR",
 "1 000.99$",
 "1,000.01$",
 "1.000,10 EURO");

$new_prices = array();
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    $new_prices[] = parseFloat(preg_replace("/[^0-9,\.]/", "", $price));
}

print_r($new_prices);
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1000 [3] => 1000.99 [4] => 1000.01 [5] => 1000.1 )
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I tried Michiel function too but did not get it to work well. You solution has problems with "22 000,76" and "22.000". So I tried to build my [own version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9111507/956397).

Comment: The above shouldn't have any problems with "22 000,76" assuming that it means "22000.76" and not "2200076.00". However your 2nd example won't work because it's not a float. A simple check on the 3rd last character would fix that though.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but parseFloat_Nick() did return some odd "0" [for me](http://jsbin.com/idozuc).

Answer (score 1):

price to number
number to price examples

```
<?php

    $number="1.050,50";

    $result=str_replace(',','.',str_replace('.','',$number));
    echo $result. "<br/>";
    // 1050.50

    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'tr_TR');
    echo money_format('%!.2n', $result) ;
    // 1.050,50

?>
```

Comment: I added `.UTF-8` to LC_MONETARY and tried my test strings but that did not work very well: http://codepad.org/s00IFyR5
Anyway `money_format` is interessting!

Comment: This solution only works with your current formating, what about "1 050,50" or "1 050.50" or again "1,050.50" ... It's not a global solution at all

Answer (score 1):

not perfect, but it work

```
function priceToFloat($s){
    // clear witespaces
    $s = trim($s);
    $s = str_replace(' ', '', $s);

    // is it minus value
    $is_minus = false;
    if(strpos($s, '(') !== false)
        $is_minus = true;
    if(strpos($s, '-') !== false)
        $is_minus = true;

    // check case where string has "," and "."
    $dot = strpos($s, '.');
    $semi = strpos($s, ',');
    if($dot !== false && $semi !== false){
        // change fraction sign to #, we change it again later
        $s = str_replace('#', '', $s); 
        if($dot < $semi) $s = str_replace(',','#', $s);
        else $s = str_replace('.','#', $s);

        // remove another ",", "." and change "#" to "."
        $s = str_replace([',','.', '#'], ['','', '.'], $s);
    } 
    $s = str_replace(',', '.', $s); 
    // clear usless elements
    $s = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "", $s);

    // if it minus value put the "-" sign
    if($is_minus) $s = -$s;
    return (float) $s;
}
```

working cases

```
$prices = [
    '123.456,789',
    '123,456.789',
    '123 456,789',
    '123 456.789',
    '-123,456.789',
    '(123,456.789)',
];
foreach($prices as $price)
     echo priceToFloat($price).'<br />';
```

return

```
123456.789
123456.789
123456.789
123456.789
-123456.789
-123456.789
```

Comment: This doesn't work everytime ... Imagine you're displaying some Japanese Yen, which has no decimal, but in an english format ... So you have this string : '¥123,457' well, your function will give 123.457 but it should give 123457 ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I got most of the way with the help of this particular thread, however I was still able to generate edge cases.

The main issue is the position of the decimal point and comma across currencies, so performing incremental checks is needed.

```
  //remove everything except for numbers, decimals, commas and hyphens 
    $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,-]+/', '', $value);
    
    $decimal = strpos($value, '.');
    $comma = strpos($value, ',');
    
    //check the 3rd last character
    if(!in_array(substr($value, -3, 1), [".", ","])) {

        if($comma && (substr($value, -3, 1) != ".")) {
            $value .= ".00";
        } elseif($decimal && (substr($value, -3, 1) != ",")) {
            $value .= ",00";
        }

    }

    $decimal = strpos($value, '.');
    $comma = strpos($value, ',');

    if($comma === false) //no comma must be a decimal number already
        return (float) $value;

    if($decimal < $comma){ //decimal before a comma = euro
        $value = str_replace(['.',','], ['','.'], $value);
        return (float) $value;
    }

    //comma first = traditional thousan separator
    $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
    
    return (float)$value;
```

Comment: `if(!$comma)` is a classic mistake.  This will be satisfied when `strpos()` returns `0` or `false`.

Comment: Interesting. I tried this but the result does not work for me: https://onlinephp.io/c/d33bb

Comment: @PiTheNumber I've looked at your test set, but I believe there may be some edge cases which are not clear: The method does fail when presented with numbers like this:

423,545
423.545

Where it is ambiguous as to whether this may be 423.545 or 423545

Currencies may be presented with more than the precision level of the currency so the initial method assumed that the input would contain a fully formatted number such as 

423,545.00
423.545,00

Without this, I would not think any method could handle all of the possible edge cases that exist.